# How to fetch json data from dynamic url in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, web-services, dart

I am using api that gives me list of meals
And also meal details
link = https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata

The last word is a variable
And i want to know how to parse this link to give me list of meals that user typed in the search box

Comment: https://github.com/theiskaa/quote-app check it out this repo

Comment: By the way, Arra**bb**iata is spelled with 2 **B**s ;)

Comment: Please follow this nice example from [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';


const theMealDbUrl = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=';

class TheMealDB {
  Map<String, dynamic> data;

  FutureOr<void> fetchRecipesFor(String meal) async {
    data = await NetService.getJson<Map<String, dynamic>>('$theMealDbUrl$meal');
  }

  List<String> getMealNamesMatched() {
    return (data['meals'] as List).map<String>((m) => (m as Map)['strMeal']).toList();
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var meals = TheMealDB();
  await meals.fetchRecipesFor('cake');
  print(meals.getMealNamesMatched());
}
```

Result:

```
[Pancakes, Rock Cakes, Carrot Cake, Dundee cake, Parkin Cake, Eccles Cakes, Madeira Cake, Christmas cake, Banana Pancakes, Battenberg Cake, New York cheesecake, Vegan Chocolate Cake, Tunisian Orange Cake, Honey Yogurt Cheesecake, Salted Caramel Cheescake, Peanut Butter Cheesecake, Provençal Omelette Cake, Polskie Naleśniki (Polish Pancakes)]
```

**UPDATE**: Code for `NetService` (`networking.dart`)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class NetService {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what is the code of    "NetService.getJson"

Comment: It's a simple code to get data by `http`. My code above is updated already.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, it really meant a lot.